# Implementing CPAcquireContext in custom CSP

Tags: smartcard, cryptoapi, mscapi

We want to develop custom Cryptographic Service Provider (CSP). For this we are referring following link

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380245%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

From the documents, we understood that following cryptographic functions need to be implemented for custom CSP.

1. CPAcquireContext
2. CPCreateHAsh
3. CPDecrypt etc. as mentioned in the following  link

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms925441.aspx

According to this link, CPAcquireContext function takes following arguments

```
BOOL CPAcquireContext(

  _Out_  HCRYPTPROV *phProv,

  _In_   CHAR *pszContainer,

  _In_   DWORD dwFlags,

  _In_   PVTableProvStruc pVTable

);
```

but we did not find any further information(like what need to do with these arguments and how to fill HCRYPTPROV structure) about the implementation of CPAcquireContext or any other entry points mentioned in the link.

Is there any other document which explain this portion in detail?  can anyone  give further assistance in developing these functions.

Comment: Did you find any useful information on this? I am also looking for the same kind of stuff. Thanks.

Comment: We're also looking for information about that - any useful information you could share?